# find values inside a matrix  matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a vector (or a matrix) which I want to print out certain values of it.

I will explain:

Let say I have a complex array.
I want to find all the values inside the array that are between 2 to 5.
How do I do that? I dont want to find the indices of these values! I want to print out (create a new array) my desire values.

Comment: What do you mean by a complex value between 2 and 5? Do you mean the real part or absolute value is between 2 and 5?

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote `A` your input matrix.
You say `A` is complex, so there are two cases:

```
A(real(A)>=2 & real(A)<=5) %% real values between 2 and 5
A(abs(A)>=2 & abs(A)<=5) %% modulus between 2 and 5
```

Comment: I've checked it, looks like it works to me.  Here's a test case.
A = 10*randn(50,1) + sqrt(-1)*10*randn(50,1);
ans1 = A(real(A)>=2 & real(A)<=5);
ans2 = A(abs(A)>=2 & abs(A)<=5);

Comment: How is it not working? This seems right to me. Could you show your code?

Comment: let say: a=magic(5). now i want to find the values that are 2<x<5.
Now, if I write: b=(a>=2 & a<=5) I will get the place where the values appear in the matrix. THIS IS NOT WHAT I WANT: I NEED THE VALUES between 2 to five THEMSELVES and not the INDEX.

Comment: I did not write that, I wrote `b=a(a>=2 & a<=5)` with `a` between `=` and `(`